# PHP:JSON: getting error while storing data into json file

Tags: php, json

Original JSON file on server:

```
{
"4567": 6768
}
```

Code to add new data is,

```
$path = 'http://*****/variables.json';
$myVarsJson = file_get_contents($path);
$myVarsArr = json_decode($myVarsJson,true);

$myVarsArr['4587'] = 6767;  /want to add this key value pair to json and store it back on server

$myVarsJson = json_encode($myVarsArr);
file_put_contents($path, $myVarsJson);
```

After saving content file should have,

```
{
"4567": 6768,
"4587": 6767

}
```

Output I am getting is

```
Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 31 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php says: "Allows Writing  No"

Comment: No just a php webpage, and I have ssl certificate also(https is also works with my domain)

Comment: Why do you access variables.json via the http wrapper?

Comment: What do you suggest then? any other way of doing what I am doing in above code? Get JSON file from server, append new key value pair, store back the file to server.

Comment: Can't suggest anything when I don't know why you're using the http wrapper in the first place. Do you want to access a file on another server?

Comment: File is saved on my server in the directory where above php code is present, I am using namecheap hosting.

Comment: Then access the file through the local file system. `$path = 'variables.json';`

Comment: @VolkerK is right... do something like this `file_put_contents('variables.json', $myVarsJson);` ...  you can't use a URL to write the file.

Comment: yes working, thanks.